# SQL-ish : how to change enormous code into an elegant one?

Tags: sql, bigdata, taql

I have just one abhorrend table, no index, no keys, no IDs, no order, 25 columns, 19 million rows.
I am using the SQL-ish language named TaQL ("Table Query Language").

I need to select-from-where ... It sounds no problem!
However the WHERE conditions are 1683 sets of simple conditions:

```
set#1: columnA>num1 and columnB>num2 and columnC<num3 and columnD>=num4 ...
or
set#2: columnA>num189 and columnB>num274 and columnC<num321 and columnD>=num457 ...
or
set#n: ...
or
set#1683: ....
```

My current code is working fine, but it has 1683 lines in the WHERE statement. I created it by awk and regular expressions.

Is there an elegant way to reduce such enormous code?

Comment: What is the purpose of 1683 lines in the WHERE statement?  Are you trying to receive all data from the table?

Comment: I need to reduce the 19 millions of rows form that table.. The conditions I found best are those 1683 sets of conditions for exclusion. I already calculated that that will reduce the rows to 12 millions, causing undetectable problems to the final product I need, based on the 12 million rows instead of 19 million.

Comment: I am sorry, but I suspect the best “elegant” solution here is to take your data and completely refactor how it is being stored, using a system that supports the level of complexity you require. I personally favor relational database systems, but depending on your data a NoSql solution might be more appropriate. Perhaps TaQL or a third-party supporter has advanced tools or utilities that can help, but on the surface it sounds like your requirements (1683 lines in WHERE?!?) may defy any kind of simple solution.

Comment: The data is not mine. It was created by E.S.O.'s radiotelescope named A.L.M.A. They provide that data for public access in a certain format they created for such bigdata. The relational systems are far useless for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried the approach of creating a new data format the DID have some normalization to it so you could import into your own database, then you can add indexes, clean criteria keep, etc.  Maybe even adding a new column to the end of your table (or columns) as "KeepThis".

Then, apply an update YourTable set KeepThis = 1 where your criteria.. maybe even set the value equal to the condition it qualified with.  Then you could query based on those values, or even all those NOT assigned to a value and see if any merit with those records not previously realized.

Sounds like a task no matter what, but might be a nice approach to have things pre-stamped and in a database you can manage vs other source.

Comment: The radio-astronomical data comes in M.S. (Measurement Set) format. Only TaQL is able to manage all those internal structures and stuff. Of course I could create and migrate that data to another DB for analysis purposes. However, my intention is to perform changes to the data, and use it. So, I have to preserve all astronomical data structures, and that is unachievable if I transform to another DB. Therefore, I will stick to my 1683 lines in the WHERE, since they are working fine, despite its non-elegance.

Comment: @Hermenegildo, understood, but if you wanted an alternate option and comment me your email, We could possibly get me the full 1600+ entries and see if we could optimize it another way.  if so, you could delete the email comment after.